# DevExpress MailClient get control of the other windows

Tags: c#, .net, user-interface, devexpress

In the open source projects there is a `MailClient` which `DevExpress` provides.

So when I run the `MailClient` I would like to know how to handle the other windows apart from the main window. For example when you press New Mail it opens a child window and you create a new email.

How can I handle that window? Like read the edits, add buttons to it etc...

I am very new to `DevExpress` so please don't judge me if this question is very beginner question.

Comment: Hi I have edited your question. Let me explain, if you have added the right tags to your question, for example "C#" and "devexpress", you don't need to provide extra background on what DevExpress is or you are using C#, the tags can attract those who know `C#` and `DevExpress`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All Ribbon items are subscribed to the bbi_ItemClick event handler on the frmMain form. This handler calls the ButtonClick method of a current module (Mail for the "New Button"). There an instance of the Message class is created and passed to the frmEditMail form which represents the form you are talking about. You can find the code of this form in the Forms/frmEditMail files. Open its designer and as many new elements as you need.